# Fold including the top line

Tags: folding

With `foldmethod=indent`, I can create folds based on the indentation level, e.g. this

```
- foo
  - bar
  - baz
- qux
```

would be folded into this:

```
- foo
+ -- 2 lines folded ------------------------------------------------------------
- qux
```

Is it possible to include the first line of the previous level into the fold? That is,

```
+ -- 3 lines folded ------------------------------------------------------------
- qux
```

Comment: I can't see any option that would enable this in `:help fold.txt`; I think you'll have to use `foldmethod=expr` and write a small `foldexpr` function (e.g. count shiftwidth() of current line + count shiftwidth() of next line).

Comment: @MartinTournoij, I guess so too, thanks! Could you suggest a sample expression? I will accept it as an answer :)

Comment: @Rich, yes! And thank you very much for the foldexpr 